# How do I create a nested JSON using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, spring-batch, lombok

I am trying to add the BusinessInformation data in my existing JSON.

```
{
    "Original": "Web Form",
    "SubmitterNetworkName": "null",
    "SourceName": "Contact Request Form",
    "SourceKind": "Web Form",

**    "BusinessInformation": {
        "BusinessContactName": null,
        “AccountNumber”:null,
    },**

    "EmployeeName": null,
    "EmployeeDOB": null,
}
```

So I have a Spring Batch app that exports data from a database to another DB and during that run some JSON needs to be created mapping multiple columns. I am using lombok and jackson mainly for the creation of JSON.

The model sample that I have. I also tried creating BusinessInformation class.

```
package model

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ColumnNameForTheDBImImportingTo implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("Origin")
    private String Origin;

    and so on..

}
```

And then I have the Service for it.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import twc.batch.extcbk.model.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class ColumnNameForTheDBImImportingToService {
        
    private ColumnNameForTheDBImImportingTo columnNameForTheDBImImportingTo (some codes) {
      
        ColumnNameForTheDBImImportingTo columnNameForTheDBImImportingTo = ColumnNameForTheDBImImportingTo .builder().build();

        columnNameForTheDBImImportingTo.setOrigin("Web Form");
}

**Then I have a method for the object mapper.**

    private String getColumnNameForTheDBImImportingTo (ColumnNameForTheDBImImportingTo columnNameForTheDBImImportingTo ) {
        String columnNameForTheDBImImportingToStr = null;

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            columnNameForTheDBImImportingToStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(columnNameForTheDBImImportingTo );

            log.debug("columnNameForTheDBImImportingToStr {}", columnNameForTheDBImImportingToStr );


        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("getColumnNameForTheDBImImportingTo " + e.getMessage());

        }
        return columnNameForTheDBImImportingToStr ;
    }

**Then another class builds the db columns and sets the values.**
```

I've tried following the Baeldung but I don't quite understand it.

I tried creating a new class for the business information and i was thinking of inserting it in the ColumnNameForTheDBImImportingTo.

Please refer me to any useful information I can follow for this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Data transformation is a typical use case for an item processor.

The way I would implement this with Spring Batch is configure a chunk-oriented step defined as follows:

- A `JsonItemReader` to read the input file
- An item processor that adds the business information
- A `JsonItemWriter` to write the output file